# Is it hard to set up Microsoft Forefront Endpoint protection?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, microsoft-forefront

I have seen that Microsoft Forefront Endpoint protection has pretty decent pricing, although it seems to require a separate System Configuration Manager installed that's quite pricey.

I am currently running 8 Windows 2008 servers and would love to use Endpoint protection, but I wonder if it's going to be a lot of work to accomplish this due to the requirement of System Configuration Manager.

I am not sure SCCM would help me in any other way, except for anti-virus. A four digit price tag would be a bit pricey considering that the actual Forefront licenses are reasonably priced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install, configure and update FEP 2010 without using SCCM.

Extract the [FEP policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412467.aspx) from the [Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13088) and import the provided ADMX/ADML files into your domain. You can then [configure FEP using Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398027.aspx) instead of via SCCM.

Answer (score 2):

AS Jscott says you can configure it and i will operate perfectly without System Center Configuration Manager but you will lose the reports and alerts components.