# Does System Center 2012 Endpoint Protection require the use of Configuration Manager?

Tags: anti-virus, desktop, microsoft-forefront

We have a relatively small organization (~15 users), and have used the ForeFront EndPoint Protection 2010 desktop client without the use of central management, like Configuration Manager.

Now that the System Center 2012 Configuration Manager and Endpoint Protection is rolled together as one installation package, do you **have** to stand up the Configuration Manager to use the Endpoint Protection desktop client? Or can we still use the desktop client as a standalone anti-virus solution?

Comment: [No, you don't need SCCM for FEP](http://serverfault.com/questions/293142/is-it-hard-to-set-up-microsoft-forefront-endpoint-protection/293148#293148).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to have SCCM to use forefront.  You do however need it if you're planning on doing any reporting on those installed clients (i.e. compliance, tracking, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

No you can stand them up separately but I believe if you want to know things like  agent health you need SCCM.